# Keyboard shortcut for Image Size in Save For Web & Devices Panel

Tags: adobe-illustrator

In `Adobe Illustrator`, after I do `Alt`+`Shift`+`Ctrl`+`S` to open the `Save For Web & Devices` window, is there a keyboard shortcut or other way to select the `Image Size` tab in that window and input size without using the mouse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I know of. But if you need to repeat the same process of Saving for Web and Device and changing the size I would suggest recording an **Action** to do that for you. You can then either play the Action every time you need it or do a **Batch** export.

Comment: Thanks. Will try out Actions & batch export after reading up on it.